# Reinsert into "First Posts" review queue after edit

Tags: feature-request, review

New users are often downvoted because they don't realise how serious we are bout question quality. Some questions become much better after editing/clarification, but then the damage of the "downvote squad" may not be able to be revoked.

I propose that questions from new users with a negative score are reinserted into the "First Posts" queue after editing. This way they get more eyes on the post and we are able to show to the new user that good posts are rewarded; that it is indeed worthwhile to fix a broken question.

An alternative proposal is a new review queue for all negatively-scored questions that are edited, in line with the "Reopen" queue.

<sup><sub>(I have no hard feelings against the downvote squad, I just think that too few people go back and reconsider their downvotes after editing)</sub></sup>

Answer (score 6):

Speaking about SO only here, don't know if it would apply equally to other SE sites.

A more radical approach could be to insert first posts directly into the review queue before letting them onto the home page.

The speed of the review queue for these things is so high that it would appear nearly immediately and a lot of issues could be caught before the encounter with the voting public. You could liken it to the prepping of a first-time public figure :-)